# Sending data from nested fragments to parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, parameter-passing, android-nested-fragment, navigation-architecture

I have a `Fragment` `FR1` that contains several `Nested` `Fragments`; `FRa`, `FRb`, `FRc`. These `Nested` `Fragments` are changed by pressing `Buttons` on `FR1`'s layout. Each of the `Nested` `Fragments` have several input fields within them; which include things like `EditTexts`, `NumberPickers`, and `Spinners`. When my user goes through and fills in all the values for the `Nested` `Fragments`, `FR1` (the parent fragment) has a submit button.

How can I then, retrieve my values from my `Nested` `Fragments` and bring them into `FR1`.

1. All `Views` are declared and programmatically handled within each `Nested` `Fragment`.
2. The parent `Fragment`, `FR1` handles the transaction of the `Nested` `Fragments`.

I hope this question is clear enough and I am not sure if code is necessary to post but if someone feels otherwise I can do so.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is how I add my `Nested` `Fragments`:

```
tempRangeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.settings_fragment_tertiary_nest, tempFrag)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

    scheduleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.settings_fragment_tertiary_nest, scheduleFrag)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    alertsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.settings_fragment_tertiary_nest, alertsFrag)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

    submitProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            constructNewProfile();
        }
    });
```

where my `constructNewProfile()` method needs the values from my `Nested` `Fragments`.

```
public Fragment tempFrag = fragment_profile_settings_temperature
        .newInstance();
public Fragment scheduleFrag= fragment_profile_settings_schedules
            .newInstance();
public Fragment alertsFrag = fragment_profile_settings_alerts
        .newInstance();
```

The above refers to the fields of the parent fragment; and how they are initially instantiated.

Comment: also have a look at my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721218/receive-fragment-result-in-navigation-component-fragment and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680327/toolbar-icon-handling-using-navigation-component

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The best way is use an interface:

1. Declare an interface in the nest fragment

   ```
   // Container Activity or Fragment must implement this interface
   public interface OnPlayerSelectionSetListener
   {
       public void onPlayerSelectionSet(List<Player> players_ist);
   }
   ```
2. Attach the interface to parent fragment

   ```
   // In the child fragment.
   public void onAttachToParentFragment(Fragment fragment)
   {
       try
       {
           mOnPlayerSelectionSetListener = (OnPlayerSelectionSetListener)fragment;

       }
       catch (ClassCastException e)
       {
             throw new ClassCastException(
                 fragment.toString() + " must implement OnPlayerSelectionSetListener");
       }
   }


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       onAttachToParentFragment(getParentFragment());

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Call the listener on button click.

   ```
   // In the child fragment.
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       switch (v.getId())
       {
           case R.id.tv_submit:
               if (mOnPlayerSelectionSetListener != null)
               {                
                    mOnPlayerSelectionSetListener.onPlayerSelectionSet(selectedPlayers);
               }
               break;
           }
       }
   ```
4. Have your parent fragment implement the interface.

   ```
    public class Fragment_Parent extends Fragment implements Nested_Fragment.OnPlayerSelectionSetListener
    {
         // ...
         @Override
         public void onPlayerSelectionSet(final List<Player> players_list)
         {
              FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
              SomeOtherNestFrag someOtherNestFrag = (SomeOtherNestFrag)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Some fragment tag");
              //Tag of your fragment which you should use when you add

              if(someOtherNestFrag != null)
              {
                   // your some other frag need to provide some data back based on views.
                   SomeData somedata = someOtherNestFrag.getSomeData();
                   // it can be a string, or int, or some custom java object.
              }
         }
    }
   ```

Add Tag when you do fragment transaction so you can look it up afterward to call its method. [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

This is the proper way to handle communication between fragment and nest fragment, it's almost the same for activity and fragment.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

There is actually another official way, it's using activity result, but this one is good enough and common.

Comment: getParentFragment() only works in API 17+, so this answer should explicit this, or it isn't clear enough

Comment: @uDevel  What does `onAttachFragment(getParentFragment());` (in step 2) do? Is it in the `Activity`?

Comment: @antonio, no, it's in the nested fragment.  The point of it is to check if the parent fragment has implemented the listener so that you can interact with parent fragment from the nested fragment by calling the method defined in the listener interface.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot access onAttachFragment from v4 support library even though it is listed in documentation.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers there may be some confusion because since `Support Library v24.0.0` or API 24 in native Android, the Google engineers introduced a new method called [**onAttachFragment(Fragment)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment)) which actually does something slightly different from the one in this answer here. uDevei just happened to choose the same method name when he wrote this answer 2 years ago. To be clear: you are not overriding the `onAttachFragment()` in the Android framework, you are **implementing** your own.

Comment: @TonyChan Thanks for clarifying the confusion.  Since Google created a new method with the same name, I want to update this answer with a better method name, but I can't think of a less confusing name.  The one from Google is actually named improperly, imo.  By reading on what it does, it should be called onChildFragmentAttached instead.

Comment: Update method name to onAttachToParentFragment to avoid confusion with Google's method.

Comment: getParentFragment() was the missing piece for me!

Comment: **Step 2** could well be replaced by the `onAttach(@NonNull Context context)` in the `ChildFragment`'s method, by implementing: `mOnPlayerSelectionSetListener = (OnPlayerSelectionSetListener) getParentFragment();`

Comment: But isn't this also a strong coupling of child and parent fragments, what if you want to reuse that child fragment in some activity? Can this be done via the event bus to remove a strong coupling between them? Or just go with a single activity app where you are sure that parent will always be fragment?

Answer (score 35):

Instead of using interface, you can call the child fragment through below:

```
( (YourFragmentName) getParentFragment() ).yourMethodName();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO. It's one line of code and does exactly what is needed. Wish I could upvote it more

Comment: You should avoid this solution if possible. The whole point of a fragment is that it is a re-usable section of UI. If your child fragment contains a hard-coded reference to the parent fragment, then you lose your re-usability of the child fragment. That's why interfaces are great, the parent will choose how to implement them.

Comment: There is not a case this is a good solution other than being lazy and not using fragment correctly.
If the child fragment know what class the parent fragment is, then you probably shouldn't create the child fragment, and just put the code in the parent fragment.

Comment: where should we use this? either in parent or child?

Comment: @uDevel Sometimes you have to use child Fragments - let's say you want to have tabs inside your parent Fragment. In that case, the child Fragments were probably made to work with only the parent Fragment. I guess in that case the one line solution is great.

Comment: @rozina I think you are right. There are cases where we are forced to use fragment.

Comment: There's a typo. P should be capital in getparentFragment().

Comment: Sorry.. @ganesh2shiv

Comment: This is not a good solution .Your child fragment get tightly coupled with your parent fragment

Answer (score 4):

The best way to pass data between fragments is using Interface. Here's what you need to do:
In you nested fragment:

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void OnDataPass(int i);
}

OnDataPass dataPasser;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}

public void passData(int i) {
    dataPasser.OnDataPass(i);
}
```

In your parent fragment:

```
public class Fragment_Parent extends Fragment implements OnDataPass {
...

    @Override
    public void OnDataPass(int i) {
        this.input = i;
    }

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("0");
            ((Fragment_Fr1) fragment).passData();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `onAttach(Activity a)` is now **depricated**. Instead I implemented `onAttach(@NonNull Context context)`, but `dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;` gives me an FATAL EXCEPTION: **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.myapp.OnDataPass**.

Comment: It worked when I defined: `dataPasser = (OnDataPass) getParentFragment();`. Is it bad?

Answer (score 4):

You can use share data between fragments.

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}


public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

More Info [ViewModel Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getChildFragmentManager()` and find nested fragments, get them and run some methods to retrieve input values

Comment: I use the childFragmentManager already to submit the transactions initially in my parent fragment; however when I try to call getChildFragmentManager() in some of my parent fragments' methods it returns an error.

Comment: so FR1 has method "constructFRaProfile()"; which I call after I hit submit in FR1. Should I call childFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRa");? and then start retrieving values?

Comment: I am not sure if I set my tags correctly; does android automatically set a tag for a child fragment or must it be manual?

Comment: How you are using your child fragments? Adding from code or using them in XML layout

Comment: @Jedil you can't add child fragments in XML, they have to be added programatically

Comment: Android only supports nested fragments dynamically from code so they are added to a framelayout from code. What @blacksh33p said.

Comment: @Tukajo what is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: It was just a typo @blacksh33p I fixed that problem, I am not sure how to set and get a tag I guess to make sure I am referring to the correct fragments when retrieving data.

Comment: I usually define a constant for the fragment tag to prevent errors from typos

Comment: Plus @blacksh33p; if I am replacing the fragments by using my FR1's various buttons, if I try to retrieve those values with a submit button wouldn't the values of the other nested fragments be unobtainable since they are not the currently active nested fragment

Comment: I will add some code to describe further. @blacksh33p

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50918/discussion-between-blacksh33p-and-tukajo)

Answer (score 3):

Check for `instanceOf` before getting parent fragment which is better:

```
if (getParentFragment() instanceof ParentFragmentName) {
  getParentFragment().Your_parent_fragment_method();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Passing data between fragments can be done with FragmentManager. Starting with Fragment 1.3.0-alpha04, we can use setFragmentResultListener() and  setFragmentResult() API to share data between fragments.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between)

Answer (score 0):

Too late to ans bt i can suggest create EditText object in child fragment

```
EditText tx;
```

in Oncreateview Initialize it. then create another class for bridge like

```
public class bridge{
public static EditText text = null; 
}
```

Now in parent fragment get its refrence.

```
EditText childedtx = bridge.text;
```

now on click method get value

```
onclick(view v){
childedtx.getText().tostring();
}
```

Tested in my project and its work like charm.