# Fragment interaction listeners in FragmentPagers

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am creating a tabbed application using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. In order to follow best practices and separation of concerns I have separated my app into several different fragments. Each of the fragments has an interaction listener that requires an `Activity` to subscribe to. Since I only have one activity in the entire app do I have to make the parent (tabbed navigation) activity implement all the listeners in the entire app? This seems like it would be bad practice and create one large monolithic `Activity` class that controls the flow of everything.

I have three fragments inside of another fragment that I use as a home page tab. The home page fragment implements the interfaces of the three sub fragments. The problem is that the home page fragment is not an `Activity` so the sub fragments throw an exception on `onAttach`.

What am I missing? How can I implement fragment listeners in a tabbed application without making one large and messy `Activity` class

Comment: For next time, I would suggest organizing the questions, list them out. I don't know the main problem or goal in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching further with different keywords I found a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23144683/2435006

They key was to make an `onAttachFragment(Fragment f)` method rather than using the `onAttach(Activity a)` and calling it in the `onCreate` method.

Here is the example from the answer above:

```
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    try
    {
        mListener = (OnInteractionListener) fragment;

    } catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
          throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString() + " must implement OnInteractionListener");
    }
 }


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    onAttachFragment(getParentFragment());
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a good sample related to Fragments. Here is a sample with detailed explanations @ [ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter). The listeners are at `onCreateView` method at the **Fragment**. You don't want to set a bunch of listeners in the **Activity**.

Comment: I have the listeners for button clicks related to the fragments in site the `onCreateView` in each fragment but in order to have them speak to each other they need to implement an interaction listener. The onClick handlers for the fragments call the methods in the interaction listeners so the Activity that implements the Fragments can do logic across fragments. I want the fragment that implements the two sub fragments to handle the cross-fragment logic (if that makes sense?).

Comment: @LukeP, Having child fragments inside one fragment may make sense, some have done so.  You have another option of not having any child fragment but show/hide layouts/buttons/listview or any GUI object. Would you consider that?