# Android send Data from fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm working on an Android app, I get some datas in a fragment and I want to use them in an other fragment.
So I was looking to create a bundle, get it in the activity with a simple getBasicInfos() method that return my bundle then send it to my other fragment.
But the problem is I can't use this method in my activity.

```
fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            fragment.getBasicInfos(); //Does not recognize the method
            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dashboard));
            break;
```

I want to know if there is a better way, or more simple.

Comment: Hint: you have to use callback methodology.

Comment: Is `fragment ` is `Fragment` class object or `DashboardFragment ` class which is subclass of `Fragment`?

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicate between different instances of same fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199714/communicate-between-different-instances-of-same-fragment)

Answer (score 2):

Create `Interface` in `Fragment` and implement that interface in `Activity` Then while Instantiating the `fragment = new DashboardFragment(this);` pass this as the listener and in `Fragment constructor` save this

```
public DashboardFragment(FragmentListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And then use this listener to pass the data to your `activity`.

hope this helps.

Comment: I found an other way, I created a public method     setBundle(Bundle basicInfos) then I call it in my fragment :)

Comment: That's not the preferred and efficient way.

Comment: If this helped you then please accept the answer. Thanks