# Passing Interface To Fragment From Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to send information from fragment to the main activity.

I am trying to set a `var interfaceName` in a fragment from the main activity.

I created `var menuInterface: MenuInterface` and tried to set it in `onNavigationItemSelected` using
`myFragment.menuInterface = this`

The `menuInterface` stays null for some reason... any idea why?

the `onNavigationItemSelected`

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.feedLayoutId -> {
            feedFragment = FeedFragment()
            feedFragment.menuInterface = this
            barTitle.text = "myTitle"
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout, feedFragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit()
        }
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Comment: post the full class

Comment: why should you send the interface to the fragment?
If you wanna send data from activity to fragment, you should use a bundle. If you wanna notify activity from fragment, you should use an interface.

Comment: Just implement suppose interface A in your activity and in ur fragment's onAttach method typecast context to  interface A.

Comment: tried `class FeedFragment(menuInterface: MenuInterface)` but i cant use the `menuInterface` for some reason

Comment: @rguerra i am trying to send information from the fragment to the activity

Comment: Would that help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579590/how-to-send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment/18579638#18579638

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement MenuInterface in your activity,and remove this line from ur code.

```
feedFragment.menuInterface = this
```

In ur fragment:

```
private var menuInterface: MenuInterface? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    menuInterface = context as MenuInterface
}

override fun onDetach() {
    menuInterface = null
    super.onDetach()
}
```

Comment: do not forget to call on detach

Answer (score 0):

I have already provided solution for such question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35038574/3027124

The idea is communication between activity and fragment should be done through `interfaces` or you should implement `MVVM` architecture and use the same view model for both `fragment` and `activity`.

Useful resources:

- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating
- MVVM Overview https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#overview