# Send Data from child fragment to parent fragment which is part of Main activity

Tags: android

I have Main Activity in that activity there is ReportFragment.
In that ReportFragment there is Viewpager which contains 3 other fragments.
I hav api call data in that 3 fragment.
I want to send data from 3 nested fragment to the Parent fragment i.e. ReportFragment.
which is child of Main Activity.

How to pass data in such scenario ?

Comment: You can use Otto library
Its simple and easiest solution
Tutotrial:http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/48752686831/playing-around-with-otto-on-android

Comment: I used interface for this according to this tutorial : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142956/sending-data-from-nested-fragments-to-parent-fragment    but getting someOtherNestFrag as null

Comment: Its a lot of code for little task, In my case i used Otto for communication b/w child and parent fragments and b/w service and Activity for updating UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this case

Also you can use callbacs for it, but it will be callback hell

Answer (score -1):

If your fragment extend from fragment in support library. You can use [getParentFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment())
to get instance of ReportFragment. In ReportFragment, you have to implement some method to set data from child fragment.