# how to get callback from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragment Parent and child, And Now I am trying to get some value from childFragment to parentFragment using callback.

Here is what i have tried so far:

**Adding childfragment**

```
 activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Now on buttonClick of childFragment i want to get response to parentFragment.

**Example:**

```
nearestCenter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    }
});
```

**P.S**
I know how to do with Activity to Fragment but is there any way to get callback from fragment to frag.

Comment: Use this already answered question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142956/sending-data-from-nested-fragments-to-parent-fragment

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code. Of course you should be careful about class cast exception and null pointer exception.

```
private void callParentFragmentMethod(){
    ParentFragment f = (ParentFragment) getParentFragment();
    f.someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use interface to interact like this :

```
public interface MyInterface{
  void sendMessageToParent(Parameters parameter);
}
```

Now implement this on your parent fragment like this -

```
public class ParentFragment implements MyInterface{

  public static Myinterface myinterface;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

     // Register your interface like this. 
     myinterface = this;

     return view;
}      

  @Override
  public void sendMessage(Parameters Parameters){

  }
}
```

Now from child activity call it like this:-

```
if(ParentFragment.myinterface!=null){
  ParentFragment.myinterface.sendMessageToParent(parameters);
}
```

This will do. And make sure in onDestroy of parent you assign it null like this:-

```
myinterface = null;
```

Hope this helps.